# How to mock the object manager in Typo3 unit-tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, typo3, typo3-9.x

I'm writing some unit-tests for a typo3 v9.5 extension, and I can not figure how to properly mock  objects when the under-test function is instanciating them using `GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class)->get(...)`

If possible, I'd like to use [the prophecy framework](https://github.com/phpspec/prophecy), but that's not mandatory.

For example, if the function under-test is like:

```
public function getRootline($pageUid) {
    $pageService = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class)->get(PageService::class);
    return $pageService->getRootLine($pageUid);
}
```

How could I test this and mock the Pageservice class?

I tried different variations of this solution:

```
$pageServiceProphecy = $this->prophesize(PageService::class);
$pageServiceProphecy->getRootLine($pageUid)->shouldBeCalled()->willReturn($myRootLine);

$omProphecy = $this->prophesize(ObjectManager::class);
$omProphecy->get(PageService::class)->shouldBeCalled()->willReturn($pageServiceProphecy);

GeneralUtility::setSingletonInstance(ObjectManager::class, $omProphecy->reveal());
```

But I get various cryptic errors every time.
The given version raises the error:

```
TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\Exception\NoSuchCacheException: A cache with identifier "cache_runtime" does not exist.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you should make use of [dependency injection](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/DependencyInjection/Index.html) in the class which exposes the `getRootline()` API, then you can have the `PageService` injected this way:

```php
final class MyCustomClass {
    private PageService $pageService;

    public function __construct(PageService $pageService)
    {
        $this->pageService = $pageService;
    }

    public function getRootline(int $pageUid)
    {
        return $this->pageService->getRootLine($pageUid);
    }
}
```

While testing you can inject a mock instead:

```php
$pageService = $this->prophesize(PageService::class);
$myCustomObject = new MyCustomClass($pageService->reveal());
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have precised that I'm using Typo3 9.5, and it seems the dependency injection require 10+... (I'll edit my question to complete it)

Comment: It depends. If you use Extbase, then you can use the same setup for dependency injection.

Comment: I tried, but dependency injection doesn't seems to work for me... I've added the `Configuration/Services.yaml` file, and tried both injecting via the constructor and via the `injectDependency(...)` methods, but no injection seems to be made by typo3... (although unit tests are running well since I am making the injection manually)

Comment: Up: I managed to make dependency injection works thanks to this blog: https://daniel-siepmann.de/posts/2017/typo3-extbase-injection.html. It specifies that you're supposed to instanciate your classes with `$objectManager->get(...)`, not with `makeInstance` or `new`